# Android runtime error

Tags: android

I was trying a sample android code but it gives fatal error when I try to work. Logcat message is below:

```
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565): Process: com.example.proje, PID: 14565
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.proje/com.example.proje.ActivityMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1970)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at com.example.proje.ActivityMain.<init>(ActivityMain.java:20)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post the code you're using.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> 12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1970)
> 12-23 10:23:47.436: E/AndroidRuntime(14565):  at com.example.proje.ActivityMain.<init>
> ```

You're calling `findViewById()` too early, in object initialization phase such as constructor or member variables initialization. You cannot call any activity methods like `findViewById()` before `onCreate()`. Move the call to `onCreate()`. Also place it after `setContentView()` so you can get a non-null value.